# Yii2 get параметры через слеш

Tags: php, yii2, route

Хочу настроить адреса в Yii2 следующим образом:
вместо `tests/process?id=1&q=2` должно получаться `tests/process/id/1/q/2` . Какие правила мне нужно прописать в urlManager? Спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нет необходимости указывать название параметра в таком случае. Достаточно перечислить параметры через / и запомнить в каком порядке какой параметр. Для этого в правилах можно записать.

Например вот так

```
'process/<id:\d+>/<q:d+>' => 'process',
```

Подробно в мануале https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/ru/runtime-routing#url-rules

Comment: Спасибо - я этот ответ и искал - может вы знаете - как сделать последний параметр q - необязательным?Почему то выражение ```(<q:\d+>)?``` не подходит.

Comment: Вместо плюса можно попробовать * или в контроллере `actionProcess($id, $q = '')`

Comment: Спасибо большое!!!